# Doubt regarding square root

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

During a lecture my professor said that the co domain of function $$f(x)=\sqrt{x}$$ must be $[0,\infty)$.

But I asked " can the co-domain be the whole R?"

He answered "it can't".

My doubt is that eventhough the range is [0,$\infty$),can the co domain be R or it  must be [0,$\infty$).
Please help me to clarify my doubt.Thanks .

Comment: If by co-domain you mean "a set which contains the range", then the answer should be yes. Often, though, co-domain is used to indicate the range of the function (i.e. the image of the domain).

Comment: You either misunderstood your professor, or he is wrong. You are right: the codomain can be $\mathbb{R}$, or any other subset of $\mathbb{R}$ containing the range of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

The point is, unless we are being very strict  about things, **the only condition on the co-domain is that it must contain the range**.

The definition of codomain says : *"a set that contains all the possible values of a function".*

Both the sets $\mathbb{R}$ and $[0,\infty)$ contain the range of your function, which happens  to be $[0,\infty)$. Hence, both qualify as co domains of the function.

However, if you were to say that $[0,\infty)$ is the domain of the function, then you would get  a stronger statement about the function, namely that it is one-one and onto. Therefore, it would be *recommended* for you to work with  $[0,\infty)$ as the co domain.  It would not be *mandatory* to do so.

Answer (score 1):

For a function $f\colon A\to B$ we call $A$ the *domain* and $B$ the *co-domain* of $f$. This expresses that $f(x)$ is defined and is an element of $B$ for all $x\in A$.
The *range* of the function, $$f[A]=\{\,f(x)\mid x\in A\,\}=\{\,y\in B\mid \exists x\in A\colon y=f(x)\,\},$$ is a subset of the co-domain, and *may* be a proper subset.

Thus we can consider the square-root function as a function $[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$, but just as well as a function $[0,\infty)\to \Bbb R$ (but certainly not as a function $[0,\infty)\to[1,\infty)$ and of course not $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$)

Comment: Is principle square root denote positive square root?